# Java constructor use parameter to create new list

Tags: java, constructor

New to Java. I'm trying to create a class to convert to JSON string to send as POST request using GSON. This class was created within a public class Called `BertClient`:

```
private class BertJsonRequest {
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> texts;

    public BertJsonRequest(int x, String text) {
        this.id = x;
        this.texts = new ArrayList<>();
        this.texts.add(text);
    }
}
```

How I use that:

```
 BertJsonRequest rawRequestBody = new BertJsonRequest(1, text);
 Gson gsonToJson = new Gson();
 String requestBody = gsonToJson.toJson(rawRequestBody);
```

For the line where I'm creating `new BertJsonRequest` My IDE tells me that BertClient.this cannot be referenced from a static content.

I wonder what that means.
Am I building the constructor correctly?
I think I'm not. I just want to be able to pass in a String so that constructor can create a List of String using that String.

Comment: I am suspecting that your BertClient is static or you are using some static keyword somewhere. the problem is BertJsonRequest somewhere coming under static context and as a result, this is not available. Could you add complete files so that we can assist you better?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem.  BertJsonRequest rawRequestBody = new BertJsonRequest(1, text); This line was under a Static Method. I then changed  BertJsonRequest to a static class according to IDE suggestions. But I don't understand it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood by reading your comments on other's answers was, that your `BertClientRequest` probably is an inner class.
In case it really is an inner class, and you try to call it in a static method of your containing class, it becomes apparent that you cannot instantiate your inner class as that inner class is not `static`.

```java
public class BertClient {
  private class BertClientRequest {
    /* some code */
  }
  
  static void aStaticMethod() {
    // ...
    // Inner class BertClientRequest is unknown to your static method as it is not static,
    // thus giving you a compile time error
    BertClientRequest rawRequest = new BertClientRequest(1, text);
    // ...
  }
}
```

The fix would be in this case to change your inner class to `static`:
`private static class BertClientRequest`

Answer (score 1):

Your class access modifier is set to private. Try setting the access modifier to public instead.

```
public class BertJsonRequest {
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();

    public BertJsonRequest(int x, String text) {
        id = x;
        texts.add(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed to Public but The error is still there. I think the private modifier won't be a problem since that private class is inside the BertClient class. Is that right?

Comment: You can try removing the this keyword and you can initalise the texts array outside the construtor. I'll edit my answer to reflect that

Comment: Just Tried Still the same

Comment: Do you mind posting the full file and the full error in the post?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `BertJsonRequest` is a inner class of `BertClient`. You can't instantiate `BertJsonRequest` outside of `BertClient`. You can make `BertJsonRequest` class static for this to work.